# How to find the Time Complexity of the following Recurrence Relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

The Running Time of an algorithm is represented by the following Recurrence Relation;

## T(n) = n if n<=3

## T(n) = T[n/3] + cn otherwise

How to find the Time-Complexity of this algorithm ?

I have got a one-word answer of big-theta(n). But I couldn't figure out how it is found. So I would like to know the procedure of finding the same.

Comment: I have got this from previous Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering. Glad to see the same on GeeksforGeeks portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to try unrolling the recurrence a few times to see what pattern comes up:

> T[n]
>
> = T[n/3] + cn
>
> = T[n/9] + cn / 3 + cn
>
> = T[n/27] + cn / 9 + cn / 3 + cn
>
> = T[n/81] + cn / 27 + cn / 9 + cn / 3 + cn

More generally, it seems like this recurrence works out to

> cn + cn / 3 + cn / 9 + cn / 27 + cn / 81 + ...
>
> = cn(1 + 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/27 + 1/81 + ...).

That sum is the sum of a geometric series. If that’s enough for you to crack this one, great! If not, pull up your friendly neighborhood Wikipedia and look at the formula there.

The above strategy works well in this case, but for more general recurrences it’s often helpful to use the Master Theorem, which can immediately solve many recurrences like this one. Check Wikipedia for details on that theorem and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

T(n) = T(n/3) + cn

Or   T(n/3^2) + cn/3 + cn

Or T(n/3^3) + cn/3^2 +  cn/3 + cn

and so on

At last T(n) = T(n/3^k) + cn/3^(k-1) + cn/3^(k - 2) .....   cn/3 + cn ... (1)

Now base case

n/3^k <= 3 or k >= log(base 3) (n/3), for sake of simplicity consider only equality

So the equation 1 will become

T(n) = n + cn/3^(k-1) + cn/3^(k - 2) .....   cn/3 + cn

Or n + cn(1 + 1/3 + 1/3^2 ....+ 1/3^(k-1)  which is GP

Or n + cn (1.(1 - 1/3^(k-2))/(1-1/3))

Or n + cn((3^(k-1)- 3) / 2 . 3^(k-2))

Putting the value of k into above equation

n + cn((3^(log(base 3) (n / 3^2)) / (2. 3^(log(base 3)(n/3^3))

which ultimately gives n + (3/2)cn

Or T(n) = n(1+(3/2) c) which is Theta(n)

Comment: In this particular case it turns out that the sum of the infinite geometric series is also bounded and that you don't need to truncate the sum at log_3 n. Makes the math a bit easier. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) = cn + T(n/3)
     = cn + cn/3 + T(n/9)
     = cn + cn/3 + cn/9 + T(n/27)
Taking the sum of infinite GP series. The value of T(n) will
be less than this sum.
T(n) <= cn(1/(1-1/3))
     <= 3cn/2

or we can say 
cn <= T(n) <= 3cn/2
Therefore T(n) = \theta(n)
```

> Otherwise: You can use Master Theorem also.